# How to open a different project from current project using threads or processes in C#.?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have developed a window application in VS2005 using C#. I need to integrate another project with my project

EDIT:
i.e pass a variable from 1st project to 2nd project and load the form of the 2nd project.

So i called that other project's main using,

```
namespace.className.Main(args);
```

But if i do so, when the 2nd project is open i'm not able to switch to my first project. I need to exit my 2nd project to navigate to my 1st project.

Also i noticed that the 2nd project is running in the same process of 1st project rather than a new process. So how can i solve this problem.? do i need create a new thread or new process and make the second project run in it and how to do it so that they both will be independant and i can switch between the two aplications.?

Comment: Do you want them as one process, or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
```

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following?

```
var formFrom2ndProject = new FormFrom2ndProject()
formFrom2ndProject.Show()
```

Comment: sorry as i missed this info, i need to pass a variable from 1st project to 2nd project and load the form of the 2nd project.